# Bind an array to an IN() condition in php prepared statements

Tags: php, arrays, prepared-statement, in-clause

How to bind an array to an IN() condition in php prepared statements?

Comment: What is the value of `print_r($userid_array)`;

Comment: `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT aboutme FROM members WHERE user_id IN (?)";
$userid_array = implode("','", $userid_array);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $userid_array); `

Comment: This is a question that comes up weekly. Instead of copy'n'pasting one of the ad-hoc snippets, consider using an established query frontend (as this is a long solved problem).

Comment: the value of print_r($userid_array) is 61,62,63